# How to delete subfolders and Files but not parent Folder in windows using Script?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line-interface

For Windows OS

```
d:\test1\test1\archive\*.txt
d:\test2\try\archive\*.txt
d:\test3\model\archive\*.txt
```

Output Like

```
d:\test1\
d:\test2\
d:\test3\
```

Using PowerShell or command prompts..!

Comment: Read about HOW TO ASK. Show your piece of code what you have tried so far. SO is not a script demand service. We help people when they are stuck on issues where people do post codes and errors

Answer (score 2):

As PowerShell supports [wildcards/patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1) on multiple levels of a path,
it's as simple as:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\test[1-3]\* | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Sample tree before and after running the command:

```
> tree /F
D:.
├───test1
│   └───test1
│       └───archive
│               x.txt
│
├───test2
│   └───try
│       └───archive
│               x.txt
│
└───test3
    └───model
        └───archive
                x.txt

> Get-ChildItem D:\test[1-3]\*|Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
> tree /f
D:.
├───test1
├───test2
└───test3
```

Comment: if i have random folder like


d:\Tujko\jkfg\archive\*.txt


d:\tesjh\try\archive\*.txt


d:\konica\model\archive\*.txt


Output Like ..


d:\Tujko


d:\tesjh


d:\konica

Answer (score 0):

This really is one of the most basic things you can do in PowerShell. Please try to do your research before asking questions since there are thousands of identical questions (with answers) on the internet. None the less, you'd be looking at something like below:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path d:\ | Get-ChildItem | Remove-Item
```

**UPDATED**
This will get all the folders from the D drive, then get all the files in those folders and remove them whilst leaving the directory

Comment: please read Proper Questions, already mention Do not delete parent Folder, Please give me a proper solution if you have ...

Comment: @Mahesh I have updated my answer, apologies

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell

```
Get-ChildItem D:\*\* | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

First * is for parent Folder name

Comment: This is in essence **my** answer with (not communicated) changed requirement of any parent folder..